# How to make drivers of ESPON printer?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, command, device-driver, network-printers

I have some a document that have commands of ESPON printers. now i have to make drivers to use  in an iPhone application. this is the link of that document http://qasimshah.sitesled.com/BettorSidekick/ESCPOS_Commands_FAQs.pdf

Now please tell me how i can send these commands to printer? I am confused how to get print via iPhone. Printer is not AirPrint Supported. so please guide me how to do it.

regards

Comment: As an alternative, you might want to check out Star. I've worked with the products of both these manufacturers and by far Star's SDK has a lot more samples and documentation. http://www.starmicronics.com/support/SDKDocumentation.aspx

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I presume you need the Epson Communication Libraries for iOS. Register and download at EpsonExpert.com. It will be in the technical resources section. Choose printer TM-P60.

EPSON receipt printers generally support ESC POS (native), OPOS, JPOS, OPOS for .NET (all three of these are UPOS API wrappers for ESC POS), and EPSON Advanced Printer Driver (for Windows printing APIs).

Since iOS doesn't do Java, JPOS is out.
Since iOS doesn't do OLE COM or .NET, OPOS and OPOS for .NET are out.
Since iOS doesn't do Windows Printing APIs, APD is out.

That leaves you ESC POS as the only viable language to talk to EPSON receipt printers with on iOS, unless they give you something else with the ECL package I mentioned above. ESC POS is pretty trivial.

If you need high fidelity to what's on the screen (fonts, etc), render it as a 150 DPI 8-bit or less BMP file and send it to the printer with ESC POS. If you just want to print receipts, use the ESC POS commands for printing text.

POS receipt printers use their own command sets (as opposed to PostScript or PCL) because they do special things, like paper cutting, etc.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it is possible to make printer drivers directly into your apps.

Your best chance would be to set up a AirPrint-enabled printing server to manage the Epson printer.

Also, albeit that I haven't tested this, this modules claims to be able to  [make any printer Airport Enabled](http://osxdaily.com/2010/12/01/make-any-printer-airprint-compatible/)

Comment: these are my printers EPSON TM T88, EPSON TM P60 and EPSON TM U220B and these printers are not AirPrint supported. have you read that document?

Comment: Yes, but you can set up a small printer server with a service that "translates" your printing task to the EPSON printer.

Comment: wow if i can do it, it will be great. please help me how i can do it

Comment: Also, an alternative solution, have you tried http://osxdaily.com/2010/12/01/make-any-printer-airprint-compatible/ ?

Comment: but @Nils Munch my printers are not connected with any OS these are connected with Network, these are wifi printers